# Too Much CPU Usage by /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg

Tags: linux, xorg, cpu

My CPU usage is almost 90%+
After investigating the output of htop I see, There is a process with this following Command which takes too much cpu usage

```
 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -nolisten tcp :0 vt1 -keeptty -auth /tmp/serverauth.eEvrhpxBUl
```

## take a look at the whole data

```
alamin    1635  1634 31 06:12 tty1     00:35:13 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -nolisten tcp :0 vt1 -keeptty -auth /tmp/serverauth.eEvrhpxBUl
alamin    9081 26703  0 08:04 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn Xorg
```

## lspci output

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Host Bridge -OPI (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 5500 (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB xHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP MEI Controller #1 (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller (rev 03)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev e3)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev e3)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev e3)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev e3)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP USB EHCI Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 03)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 03)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Wildcat Point-LP SMBus Controller (rev 03)
06:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 3160 (rev 83)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 07)
08:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce 920M] (rev a1)
```

## output of mpstat -P ALL

```
Linux 4.10.0-33-generic (laptop)    08/29/2017  _x86_64_    (4 CPU)

08:55:25 AM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest  %gnice   %idle
08:55:25 AM  all   47.07    0.01   18.16    4.53    0.00    0.52    0.00    0.00    0.00   29.70
08:55:25 AM    0   48.75    0.01   17.76    4.44    0.00    0.18    0.00    0.00    0.00   28.87
08:55:25 AM    1   47.76    0.02   17.03    4.06    0.00    1.59    0.00    0.00    0.00   29.55
08:55:25 AM    2   47.95    0.01   18.64    5.16    0.00    0.22    0.00    0.00    0.00   28.02
08:55:25 AM    3   43.81    0.01   19.24    4.47    0.00    0.09    0.00    0.00    0.00   32.38
```

## output of vmstat

```
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 2  0      0 5918180  57512 905904    0    0   202    28 1848 2469 48 19 29  4  0
```

If you need any more data. Just ask....

Please give me a suggestion to solve it.

Comment: Are you running remote graphical sessions/programs?

Comment: I don't think so... I am only running a i3 based WM and only working with some local configs in my editor. and my cpu usage is too much

Comment: `Xorg` is the X server, responsible for displaying graphics. So some other program is trying to display something all the time. Try to identify the culprit in `htop`, `xlsclients` etc.

Comment: Anecdote: I had zombie-ish script runs that failed because `display` wasn't installed (IIRC), but stayed alive nonetheless. Killing those processes brought `Xorg` down from ~80% to ~5%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [@dirkt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/388973/too-much-cpu-usage-by-usr-lib-xorg-xorg#comment692774_388973). The problem was of another process -- i3bar -- which was trying to display a lot all the time. I investigated a little in the config and figured out the bottleneck.

Comment: Thank you so much, i3bar was the culprit in my case too. But how did you overcome this issue? Like yes, killing i3bar is an option, but what exactly in i3bar was causing the issue?

Comment: @RishabhAgrahari It was a long time ago. I don't remember. But one thing - I use plenty scripts for i3bar, one of them was the bottleneck.

Comment: Ah, I figured it out, it was a module (block in i3blocks) which had unmet dependencies.